# getting textfield value and search result after page after click on search button in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my search page I have a textfield of zip code and when I enter Zip code in the textfield and click on search button the value of text field is loss and also search result is loss, what I do to stable textfield value of zip code and search result after click on search button. below is my view page:

```
<%= form_for :search, :url => { :method => :get, :action => :search } do |f| %>
<table width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;" width="35%">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td align="center">
                <%= text_field_tag "tf_Zip",nil,:placeholder =>'Zip' %>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
<table>
                    <% if !@user.nil? %>
                        <% @user.each do |uzr| %>
                          <tr>
                              <td bgcolor="#CCDBE0" width="40%">
                            <%= image_tag @user_img.photo.url(:small),:alt => " " %>
                              <br/>
                              <div><a style="color:blue;" href = 'profile?id=<%= uzr.id %>'><%= uzr.First_Name + " " + uzr.Last_Name %></a></div>
                              </td>
                              <td bgcolor="#CCDBE0" width="60%" style="text-align:center;">
                              <div class='buttonblck1'><a href='searchings?id=<%= uzr.id %>'>Send Request </a></div>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                        <%  end %>
                    <% end %>
</table>
<% end %>
```

and below is controller page

```
if ( !params[:tf_Zip].blank? or params[:tf_Zip] != "" )
   @user = User.find(:all,:conditions=>['"user_Zip" = ? and "id" != ? ',params[:tf_Zip], current_user.id])
end
```

Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply.'
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

`form_for` is meant to be used with an instance of `ActiveModel` or `ActiveRecord`.
Use `form_tag`, if you want to create a form, that is not based on an object.

Second:

as you have not object, where the attributes are stored, you have to provide them yourself.
The value is defined in the second parameter of `text_field_tag`
i.e. in your controller:

```
@zip_search = params[:tf_Zip].presence
if @zip_search
  @user = ...
end
```

and in your view:

```
<%= form_tag url_for( :controller => :search, :action => :search), :method => :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "tf_Zip", @zip_search, :placholder => 'Zip' %>
<% end %>
```